# Help my girlfriend in finding the hidden message

Tags: cipher, crosswords

I've been with my girlfriend, who's birth date is 20 February, for almost three years now.
I would like to hand her a challenge with a crossword puzzle. (not really a crossword I think, but something similar)
So I decided to create one and ask her to find the secret hidden message inside.

[image: Crossword puzzle]

All words are horizontal, and the secret message is the one inside the red box.

```
1. Standing in line.
2. Relating to visual art, especially involving drawing, engraving, or lettering.
3. Repairing synonym.
4. To shutdown the computer is equal to:
5. A person or thing that is being discussed, described, or dealt with.
6. 3.14159265359....
7. Life-supporting component of the air.
8. You wear it in hand
9. Normally it has a circular shape, and yummiiii….
10. Found between a couple.
11. A place to put all kind of criminals.
12. Go out, look up, you see it.
13. Something to have fun with when bored
14. Birds do it, we can't.
```

Can you help her find the hidden message, in case she tried to find the answer here when I am not looking?

Hint:

> Two steps are needed to solve it,
>  First one is to find the words
>  Second one is to decipher the message.

Comment: is oxygen really not the answer for 7? Doesn't fit.

Comment: @Brisingr I used plural, don't know why ><

Comment: Well the answer is very obvious, just need to solve the crossword :P

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil As I told benzene, the answer is very obvious, and I am actually really going to hand my girlfriend this puzzle :) She's learning English so she won't easily solve it herself. Well, I will see ;)

Comment: @PaulKaram oh good luck! She might find the cipher difficult if she doesn't know about ROT or Caesar ciphers, but you could always tell her about that if she solve the crossword.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Yeah of course I will tell her, I used ROT6 due to 26-20(her birthdate), and will help her a little bit :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The clues are

> 1. **Q**ueue
>  2. graphi**C**
>  3. **F**ixing
>  4. turnof**F**
>
>  5. **S**ubject
>  6. p**I**
>  7. **O**xygens
>
>  8. **G**love
>  9. fond**U**
>  10. **L**ove
>  11. jai**L**
>  12. **S**un
>
>  13. **G**ame
>  14. fl**Y**

put 'em together:

> QCFF SIO GULLS GY

then

> shift each letter forward 6 places in the alphabet

and the message is

> WILL YOU MARRY ME

Comment: ...Which was immediately obvious from the blanks and context but I did not have the time to work out the puzzle that goes with.

Comment: If I told you that this word ending with 'u' is a sweet, can you figure it out?

Comment: I can't even think of a five letter word ending in 'u' other than haiku

Comment: fondu? Not exactly a 'circular' per se, but is usually served in a circular container.

Comment: Well, I am not excellent in English and wanted to try something, and just for information, I am really going to hand her this puzzle. It's not just made for this site ;), and since she's learning English from scratch now, I didn't want to make it so hard, hence why it was so obvious and easy. Yes, the word is Fondu.

Comment: @benzene I will accept the answer for now, but make sure to edit and update the fondu word :)

Comment: @benzene I can [find](http://www.litscape.com/word_tools_mammoth_uncensored/word_ends.php) 66 five-letter words ending in `u`

Comment: @EngineerToast four out of every five of those sounds like it could be a sweet I've never heard of.

Comment: Nice answer. +1ed. Welcome to Puzzling.SE :)